# How to copy address of specific file / folder in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

In Windows, to get the complete path of selected file / folder, we just right click on it and select properties & can copy the path of selected file / folder.

But I didn't find any option in the *Get Info* view of a selected file / folder, address is given but we can't select or copy it.

Is it possible to copy path from info screen? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where do you need the path? Normally you can just drag&drop the file or folder to the interface where you need the path. This works in the Terminal app for example.

Comment: OOhh ! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

This an old question and there is now another way to copy the pathname that may be easier than what's been suggested (unless the **Terminal** is the intended destination for the pathname in which case dragging the file to **Terminal** is easier). It has existed at least since Yosemite and possibly before.

To copy a file's pathname, select the file in the Finder, press and hold the *Option* key and open the ***Edit*** menu where you should see that the usual ***Copy `<filename>`*** menu selection should now be shown as ***Copy `<filename>` as Pathname***.

Comment: Or simply press Option+Command+c

Comment: This is the actual answer

Answer (score 1):

Command G ("Go to..") will open a dialog box where you can type in the path that happens to default to the current path of your active window.

Answer (score 1):

In my OS (10.5.7) the "Go to folder" command is [shift+command+G] and it isn't pointing to my active window path.
The Terminal thing works like a charm. Thank you!